# Access managed files, local files and remote files ssh during Jenkins pre-build stages

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a parametrized build and I'd like to populate parameter values based on contents of files/directories on the local slave and/or on a remote box accessible via ssh.

It's not a problem to access local and remote files during build stages, but I need to make it work in an Active Choice Plugin (or something similar).

Apparently, sh function doesn't work, but some Java-like Groovy API is still available (as described here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Active+Choices+Plugin)

```
jenkinsURL=jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getRootUrl()

def propFile=vPropFile //name of properties file
def propKey=vPropKey // name of properties key
def relPropFileUrl=vRelPropFileUrl // userContent/properties/
def propAddress="${jenkinsURL}${relPropFileUrl}$propFile"
def props= new Properties()
props.load(new URL(propAddress).openStream())
def choices=[]

props.get(propKey.toString()).split(",").each{
    choices.add(it)
}

return choices
```

I wonder if it's possible to access managed files the same way or better yet to access something remotely using SSH.

Is there an API for that?

Comment: What is the purpose to have parameters if they are populated by some external source ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a solution that would allow to SSH during during Active Choices parameter script execution.

However, I was able to use configuration file(s) managed by Jenkins. Here's the code that can be run from the Active Choices parameter script:

```
def gcf = org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles.get()
// Read different file based on referencedParameter ENVIRONMENT
def deploymentFileName = 'deployment.' + ENVIRONMENT + '.properties'
def deploymentFile = gcf.getById(deploymentFileName)
def deploymentProperties = new Properties();
deploymentProperties.load(new java.io.StringReader(deploymentFile.content))
def choices = []
// Make use of Properties object here to return list of choices
return choices
```

Later in the main Groovy Script of the pipeline it's possible to update file the same way, but the file has to be read/loaded again as the script context is different:

```
def gcf = org.jenkinsci.plugins.configfiles.GlobalConfigFiles.get()
def deploymentFile = gcf.getById(deploymentFileName)
def deploymentProperties.load(new java.io.StringReader(deploymentFile.content))

// Update deploymentProperties as necessary here.

def stringWriter = new java.io.StringWriter()
deploymentProperties.store(stringWriter, "comments")

// Content of the deploymentFile object is immutable.
// So need to create new instance and reuse the same file id to overwrite the file.
def newDeploymentFile = deploymentFile.getDescriptor().newConfig(
    deploymentFile.id, deploymentFile.name, deploymentFile.comment, stringWriter.toString())
gcf.save(newDeploymentFile)
```

Of course, all necessary API permissions have to be granted in Jenkins.